# How to do adding a new item in listbox from a popup window?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, popup

Hi i am trying new things these days. I am working on an application in `rails 3.0.6`.

In my application in a form I want to add a new item in a list box by popping a window. i. e. I have a link `"add new"` with list box, when user click on that link a popup open with form and when a user fill up all the details and save the entry, the pop up should close and the item should be added in the list box. I am apologies if any one suggest a good answer in advance.

Hi am using "nyroModal" for this and i have to just link the form i want to pop up

```
<%= link_to 'Feedback', new_feedback_path, :class => "nyroModal" %>
```

I got this from:

```
nyroModal - jQuery Plugin
 * http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com
```

and nothig to do with controller, just disabling the layout for that window.

Comment: You need do it by Javascript.

Comment: Hi @shingara i have done this but have problem, when i fill the details and hit the submit button it redirects me on index page of the list box's item's which are stored in other table, and i want to stay on same form, thanks for your answer.

Comment: paste your controller and javascript please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey ravi try this in your feedback controller in create method when you want to redirect on back screen.

`format.html { redirect_to :back, {:notice =>  'Feedback was successfully created.'}}`

Comment: Thanks friends this is really same as i want.